# Is it true that $m_*(E) = m^*(E)$? (Lebesgue inner and outer measures)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ we can define the inner and outer Lebesgue measure as:
$$ m^*(E) = \inf \{ m(U) : E \subseteq U, \text{ $U$ is open } \} $$

$$ m_*(E) = \sup \{ m(F) : F \subseteq E, \text{ $F$ is closed } \} $$

I know that if $E$ is measurable then $m^*(E) = m_*(E)$, but is it true for all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Could someone help me providing an example when the equality does not hold?

Comment: It's stronger : $E$ is measurable $\iff$ $m_*(E)=m^*(E)$.

Comment: @joshua That equivalence holds when $m^*(E)$ is finite.

Comment: This [5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) ([minor correction](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/QaaZ0eMcoGQJ)) includes a lot of statements and references about sets having different inner and outer measures. A [tl;dr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) take-away for your purposes is that the standard ways (Vitali sets & Bernstein sets being probably the best known) of obtaining nonmeasurable sets actually produce sets such that $0 = m_*(E) < m^*(E).$ [An extreme case.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/119693/15780)